# How can I apply a theme to a table using jQueryUI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, themes

I need to theme some tables, and I want to accomplish this using jQueryUI.

Where can I find some examples, resources, links and demos of this?

Comment: terribly vague, but have you looked at http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used this method with great success:

http://www.ke-cai.net/2010/01/theme-your-table-with-jquery-ui.html

You could always apply the classes directly to the table to reduce javascript overhead as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use jquery to theme the table? Maybe I'm missing something here, but isn't bringing in jquery + jquery.ui a bit of an extreme overhead for what could just be done through CSS?

Comment: Of course that would be too much.  But if you've loaded jQuery UI for something else in the project already, it's just a small matter theme your tables as well.